# Solving $\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over x^4-81}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

solve the following $$\int_0^{\infty} {dx \over x^4-81}?$$

my approach:

$$\int {dx \over x^4-81}=\int {dx \over (x^2+9)(x^2-9)}$$

used partial fractions

${1\over18}\int ({1 \over x^2-9}-{1 \over x^2+9})dx={1\over 18}\int {dx \over x^2-9}-{1\over 18}\int {dx \over x^2+9}$

for first part, used partial fractions

$${1\over 18}\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over x^2-9}={1\over 108}\int_0^{\infty} ({1 \over x-3}-{1 \over x+3})dx$$$$={1\over 108}\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^{t} ({1 \over x-3}-{1 \over x+3})dx$$
$$={1\over 108}\lim_{t\to \infty}(\ln|x-3|-ln|x+3|)_0^{t}$$$$={1\over 108}\lim_{t\to \infty}(\ln|{t-3\over t+3}|)$$ $$={1\over 108}\lim_{t\to \infty}(\ln|{1-3/t\over 1+3/t}|)={1\over 108}\cdot 0=0$$

for second part, I substituted $x=3\tan t$, $dx=3\sec^2 t\ dt$
$${1\over 18}\int_0^{\infty} {dx \over x^2+9}={1\over 18}\int_0^{\pi/2} {3\sec^2t\ dt \over 9\sec^2t}={1\over 54}\int_0^{\pi/2}dt={\pi\over 108} $$
adding two values, my answer becomes $0+({-\pi\over 108})=-{\pi\over 108} $

Can I do this by other way which is simpler than my method? thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure this integral diverges around $x=3$. In your derivation, this arises when you get logarithms after (incorrect, I believe) integration of $\frac 1 {x-3} + \frac 1 {x+3}$

Comment: As @Dmitry says this integral diverges because for $x\to3$ we have$$\frac1{x^4-81}\sim\frac1{108(x-3)}$$the value that you have calculated is in fact the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done much faster: every well-bred young people should know by heart the following formulæ:

- $\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{a^2+x^2}=\frac1a\,\arctan\Bigl(\frac xa\Bigr)$,
- $\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{a^2-x^2}=\left.\begin{cases}\dfrac1a\,\operatorname{argtanh}\Bigl(\dfrac xa\Bigr)&-a<x<a\\\dfrac1a\,\operatorname{argcoth}\Bigl(\dfrac xa\Bigr)& x<-a \:\text{ or } \:x>a\end{cases} \right\rbrace=\frac1{2a}\,\ln\biggl|\frac{a+ x}{a-x}\biggr|,$ $\quad -a<x<a$.

These formulæ yield instantly
$${1\over18}\int_0^\infty\! \Bigl({1 \over x^2-9}-{1 \over x^2+9}\Bigr)\,\mathrm dx=\frac1{18}\biggl[\frac16\ln\biggl|\frac{3-x}{3+x}\biggr|-\frac13\arctan\Bigl(\frac x3\Bigr)\biggr]_0^\infty=\frac1{18}\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac\pi 2$$

Comment: This does not say anything about the singularity $x = 3$.

Comment: That's right. I just wanted wanted to show the antiderivatives  were easy to compute with the relevant formulæ in mind.

Answer (score 5):

You can start by getting rid of the constant $81$,

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^4-81}=\frac1{27}\int\frac{dt}{t^4-1}.$$

Then

$$\int\frac{dt}{t^4-1}=\frac12\int\frac1{t^2-1}-\frac12\int\frac1{t^2+1}.$$

The secont term yields $\arctan t$, and the first, if you are aware, $\text{artanh }t$.

Explicitly,

$$\int\frac{dt}{t^2-1}=\frac12\int\frac{dt}{t-1}-\frac12\int\frac{dt}{t+1}=\frac12\log\left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|.$$

---

But, there is a but: the integration range contains a singularity at $t=1$ and the integral is improper.

We can obtain the Cauchy principal value by noting that $\dfrac1{t-1}$ is antisymmetric around $(1,0)$ and we can use

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a\left(\frac1{t-1}-\frac1{t+1}\right)dt=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_2^a\frac{dt}{t-1}-\int_0^a\frac{dt}{t+1}\right)=\lim_{a\to\infty}(\log a-\log a)=0.$$

Comment: I am done now, thank you.

Comment: I put the second downvote. Any reason I shouldn't? It's already stated in comments to the post that the integral diverges, yet there are some "solutions" popping up (without any mention of Cauchy principal value at that time; moreover, even with it it's an answer to a different question). Also, if you didn't finish your solution, then why did you post it?

Comment: @Dmitry: safety. Downvotes without explanation are of little use.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\mrm{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over x^{4} - 81} } =
{1 \over 27}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{4} - 1} =
{1 \over 108}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/4} \over x - 1}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 108}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-1}^{\infty}
{\pars{x + 1}^{-3/4} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 108}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 + x}^{-3/4} - \pars{1 - x}^{-3/4} \over x}
\,\dd x + {1 \over 108}\int_{1}^{\infty}{\pars{x + 1}^{-3/4} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-\,{\mrm{arccoth}\pars{2^{1/4}} + \arctan\pars{2^{1/4}}\over 54} +
{1 \over 81}\ \mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{{3 \over 4},{3 \over 4};{7 \over 4}\;-1}}
\\[5mm] \approx &\ -0.0291
\end{align}